# How to delete android virtual device release version, in android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I selected **Oreo 8.0** as Android virtual device **release name**. Now I want to delete that release version and download another. How do I delete **Oreo 8.0**?

Also this is my first question here. :)

Answer (score 3):

Tools > AVD Manager > click on the triangle > Delete
**or**
open File Explorer and folow this path:

```
C:\Users\Your Name\.android\avd\
```

Delete the folder of that device.

Answer (score 1):

it simple, just right-click an AVD and select Delete. Or click Menu and select Delete.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete **Virtual Device**, delete it in `C:\Users\"Username"\.android\avd` directory. If you want to delete android 8.0 system image, Go to **SDK Manage**r from settings or android studio toolbar and then select or unselect android versions as you want.

Comment: how to open SDK Manager? please elaborate the full step...

Comment: you can find it in  Settings --> Appearance & Behavior --> System Settings --> Android SDK. It is available in toolbar too